# EF 5.0 targeting multiple databases

Tags: sql, oracle, orm, entity-framework-5

We started using EF 5.0 with MVC 4 and everything was working great. Our application is a product where the DB can be dynamic (SQL, Oracle, AS400 etc). So we created entities and map it to DB based on Connection String. If ConnectionString says Oracle we set the dbcontext connection to Oracle.

Now the problem is there is a table in SQL and Oracle with same datatype number(18,0) and if Entity datatype is set to Double, it works with Oracle but not with SQL.

Because Oracle to Entity datatype mapping for number(18,0) is double but SQL number(18,0) is decimal in EF5.0

IS there a way that I use same entity mapping targetting dynamic DB's (SQL or Oracle or AS400)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, until now I only found this:

http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Multiple-database-support-with-Entity-Framework.aspx

I´m using "database first". Maybe "Code first" will solve it, but it took 40 seconds at the first database connection after program has started, I think all the SSDL definition is retrieved dynamically from database in that 40 seconds (every time program is started!). This was unaccetable for me so I decided to use "database first" where all the schemainformation is prestored in the edmx file (SSDL-part). But this is not database independet, as I just have learned.